# Upload different image sizes or a single size to be processed later?

Tags: java, image, image-processing

My website allows users to upload profile images, which are then represented in several (about 3 or 4) different sizes around the site.

As the site grows, there is always the possibility that the image sizes will need to be tweaked, or new image sizes will be needed later.

How does a site like Facebook or Twitter handle this? Do they process the image into different sizes right at the upload time, or do they store higher quality images and process them server-side when needed?

Is there a common way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The different sized images would most likely be cached somewhere, rather than processed at access-time each time.  When the upload occurs, you would create all the sizes you will need and store them (in files or your database).  This method uses the most disk space to store all image sizes, but places all the processing load at the moment of upload, allowing for faster access later.

Alternatively, if the load isn't expected to be heavy you could create different sizes at the first moment those sizes are accessed, and then store them for future use.  This method therefore uses less disk space by only creating images that are actually used, but would inhibit access times the first time an image size is used. Future access times would be fast, accessing a cached image.

#### Addendum for larger loads

Consider performing the image processing on a separate worker server. Ideally, the front end and the worker servers would share the storage mount to which images are uploaded and stored,  saving transfer bandwidth between them.  At the moment of upload of the original, the main application places the image in a queue for processing by the worker. The images cannot be available for use until processed, but the processing load remains independent of the front end, so it does not have much direct impact on the end-user experience.

Depending on just how many uploads you expect per minute, the worker process could be as simple as a cron job running every minute to poll a table of pending upload tasks (registered by the main application), perform the conversions, and update the table when they have been completed.  If one minute is too long to wait however, you would need a continuous running worker process to be polling for new tasks.  Obviously this is more complex to implement.

*No matter what you do though, do not regenerate the alternative image sizes each time you need them.  Store them somewhere.*

Comment: Wouldn't having a separate server incur in costs of data transfer between these two? lets say, I have the front end amazon server which receives a picture along with some information through a POST. If this server had to send the picture into another server wouldn't the bandwidth costs increase by a lot?

Comment: @LuisOscar I meant to note that the worker and front end have shared access to img storage. That may be possible with amazon but I don't know the platform offerings well

Comment: Oh as a matter of fact it does, and transfers between their servers are free. Just a last question, is there a special way to do this? a library for java perhaps? I am not very familiar with java. Thanks!

Comment: @LuisOscar Java has bindings for the ImageMagick library which would handle the image processing.  http://www.jmagick.org/index.html

Answer (score 2):

They process the image into different sizes right at the upload time.

Upload happens once, viewing could happen thousands of times. Processing on upload reduces the work for the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get better result:

Upload a best needed resolution of image on server(from client side) and the after scale that image in the lower required size of image and save those images byte array in database, like original image, thumbnail of original image and other sizes.

Send only that image to client which he really want to show, like send thumbnail for profile pic and gallery view and original image on click on any thumbnail. Keep image URL some how similar for thumbnail and original.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions:

Put limits on file size, resolution and format of the upload and store the original image.

Alternatively: Impose less strict limits, convert the original image, store the converted image instead of the original.

Thumbnails are (presumably) accessed the most often, and are (presumably) the smallest, so it makes sense to store them. To store an image that's say a 1/5th (or less) of the size of the original is hardly significant. These can be stored upon upload.

If you don't want to store all the other-sized images, some sort of Least-Recently-Used or Most-Often-Used cache may be in order. These should be reasonably simple to implement with image unique IDs, a queue of IDs for each size and a directory that stores the cached images with file-names generated from the unique ID and desired image size.

If the sum of all the other image sizes is much less than the original image size (say less than half), it wouldn't be the worst idea to just store all of them.

I'm sure finding an open-source Java image resizer wouldn't be much effort.

[ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) is a decent, but reasonably basic, image processing API. Not sure if it can do resizing. I see it has some caching functionality.